# Difference between Snappy and Click

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-core, click-packages

I don't understand the difference between Snappy and Click. Both allow for image based system updates. Both use AppArmor to confine apps. Soon Click will run on the desktop, phone and tablet and Snappy will run on servers and IoT devices. I thought convergence was all about having the same OS between all of these devices.

Could we see them merge in the future?

It'd be great if someone could explain this to me because both of these tools sound like they're serving the same purpose, and I don't want to learn 2 identical tools.

Comment: "convergence" has nothing to do with Snappy and Click. It is still the same OS. And when do you expect to be using a Snappy file? I doubt a user will be able to create those since they are intended to update system files (and I would assume those updates are limited to carriers and canonical).

Comment: I saw an example which installed docker on a Snappy system using the snappy command. Therefore if I want to create my own snappy application I will need to package it for snappy systems as well. Regarding convergence, right now snappy is being used on the server and click is used on the client-side. Will click be used on the server side as well? Why not replace snappy with click or vice versa? There's probably something I'm not getting correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Michael Hall, a Canonical employee](http://mhall119.com/about/), answered this question on Reddit:

> "Snappy is an evolution of click, which will eventually replace clicks
>   on the phone. Snappy Personal is to phone and desktop what Snappy Core
>   is to cloud and IoT, it's the base install image that provides the
>   minimum functionality needed for you to get started." - [An important notice for Ubuntu Desktop Next users : Ubuntu](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/33kybn/an_important_notice_for_ubuntu_desktop_next_users/#cqlw77s)