# What are Snap packages and what are the difference between Click packages and Snap packages?

Tags: click-packages

Are they just same?

Launchpad can build Snap packages but not click packages.

Comment: Should I keep this question or update this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/337969/what-are-click-packages

Comment: Possible repetion of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654024/are-click-packages-obsoleted-by-snappy-packages

Comment: @Peter that question does not properly explain the differences.

Comment: or perhaps this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/635560/536378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click packages are isolated, so run in confinement with a "personal" directory and thus cannot provide dependencies to other programs. Intended originally for Ubuntu Mobile/Touch but later for the desktop, they were directed towards user applications because of their bundled dependencies and protected nature (e.g. you could have multiple versions of the same application, all using different libraries and all unaware of each other).

Ref: https://click.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And the answer to a familiar (to you!) question here: [What are Click packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337969/what-are-click-packages)

---

Snappy packages are an iteration of the packaging concept, in that they *can* provide functions to other packages, and don't have to be confined. They can thus be the basis for system-wide applications/functions as well.

Ref: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/04/ubuntu-desktop-to-eventually-switch-to.html

Comment: "they can provide functions to other packages" What does that mean?

Comment: As I understand it, it's that they can use libraries and functions bundled into other Snappy packages versus Click, which only have access to the system libraries and any dependencies with which they were bundled. In other words, something like Imagemagick could be installed as a .snap, but then other .snap graphics programs could use those routines as well vs having to bundle them completely every time. "Isolated dependencies", if you like.